# Can't display object, AG grid is always empty (Angular AG Grid)

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am getting my object inside of my child component but I could not find a way to display it and the AG grid is always empty.
[This is a screenshot of what I am currently getting, I am displaying rowdata as {{ rowData | json }} to see if I am receiving it in child component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSQbT.png)

this is the html in my parent component:

```
<div class="connections grid grid-cols-3" *ngIf="bankingConnections$ | async as connections">
                <app-banking-connections-overview [rowData]="connections"> </app-banking-connections-overview>
            </div>
```

And this is how I declared the observable that I am trying to display

```
bankingConnections$?: Observable<SaltEdgeConnection[]>;
```

this is the code inside of my child component html:

```
<app-ag-grid-client-side-table
    [columnsDefs]="bankingConnectionsColumnsDefs"
    [rowData]="rowData"
></app-ag-grid-client-side-table>
```

And this is my child component:

```
export class BankingConnectionsOverviewComponent {
    @Input() rowData: any[] = [];

    bankingConnectionsColumnsDefs: IBankingConnectionsColumnsDef[] = [
        new TextCellColumn({
            // Bank
            headerName: this.translateService.instant('internal.banking.providerName'),
            field: 'providerName',
            sortable: true,
            floatingFilter: true
        }) as IBankingConnectionsColumnsDef,
        new TextCellColumn({
            // Status
            headerName: this.translateService.instant('internal.banking.status'),
            field: 'status',
            sortable: true,
            floatingFilter: true
        }) as IBankingConnectionsColumnsDef,
        new MediumDateCellColumn({
            // Verbunden am
            headerName: this.translateService.instant('internal.banking.createdAt'),
            field: 'createdAt',
            sortable: true,
            floatingFilter: true
        }) as IBankingConnectionsColumnsDef
    ];
    constructor(private bankingService: BankingService, private translateService: TranslateService) {}
}
```